# Conda environment sometimes words, sometimes not

Tags: python, macos, shell, conda

I have been wanting to play with rllab (https://github.com/rll/rllab) for a while, and followed all their instructions to install it. Right now, along with a lot of junk I will probably want removed in the future, I have my terminal where I can type

```
source activate rllab3
python
```

which will get me into a python shell where I can import rllab and play with it.

However there are two weird behaviours that I am not being able to fix. I had the environment active in one terminal window, opened another one, activated the environment and the python shell, and all import calls to rllab failed. I brought up another python shell on my initial terminal, and it imported rllab just fine. So having two shells set for the same environment, with the same python executable running, sometimes both work, sometimes only one works, sometimes none works. When they work, calling `rllab.__file__` prints the path to the correct file, when it doesn't work I can run

```
import rllab
```

with no problems, however calling `rllab.__file__` results in an `AttributeError`.

The second problem came when I decided to try out some editors for debugging. After managing to get it to work (sometimes...) with Atom, I decided to see what had come bundled with Anaconda, and decided to give Spyder a try. I activated the environment, installed Spyder in it, and I keep getting import errors. I tried setting PYTHONPATH inside Spyder to point directly to the rllab directory, and it still didn't work.

I am on Mac OS X 10.9, latest version of Anaconda.

Comment: how did you create the environment, and how did you install rllab? I know you said you followed their instructions, but I'm asking you to copy/paste your actual console commands.

Comment: (my suspicion is that you're in the `rllab` source directory or have a file called `rllab.py`)

Comment: Correct. `rllab` is in `~/rllab`. By default my terminals opened in `~` and `import rllab` found the first folder, but not the modules within. cd'ing into that folder and running python inside it worked. I went to check and I noticed PYTHONPATH was not set in the terminals where it did not work. Running Spyder from the console instead of Anaconda-Navigator also did the trick. Thanks!